# REGEX for blocks

Tags: python, regex

I have a lot of START/STOP text blocks in a text file.

```
start
value1 as5q
value3 dd9w
type b
value6 dp1p
stop

start
value1 as
value2 er
type a
stop

start
value1 as5
value2 er2
type c
value4 dd1
stop
```

I need to extract the value1's value when the type is "a".

Please, could you help me? I tried a lot of ways but I'm still newbie with regex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you required to use regex?  This doesn't seem like a good use case for it to me.

Comment: Yes, I'm required to use regex.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
my_text="""start
value1 as5q
value3 dd9w
type b
value6 dp1p
stop

start
value1 as
value2 er
type a
stop

start
value1 as5
value2 er2
type c
value4 dd1
stop"""

blocks = re.findall("(?:start)(.*?)(?:stop)",my_text,re.DOTALL)
```

this utilizes non-capturing groups, non-greedy match operator, and re.DOTALL flag in order to match newlines

Comment: [`start(.*?)stop`](https://regex101.com/r/82BeTU/1/) works as well, no need for non-capturing groups.

Comment: With these answers I can continue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this output?

```
as5q
as
as5
```

Then, you may try this `regex`

```
(?s)start.*?value1\s+(a[^\s]*)
```

[Demo,,,](https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/29/) in which target values(`value1`'s value containing prefix '`a`') is captured to `group 1` (`\1`)

In `python`script, it may be like this

```
import re
ss="""  copy&paste sample text in this area  """

regx= re.compile(r'(?s)start.*?value1\s+(a[^\s]*)')
for m in regx.finditer(ss):
    print(m.group(1))
```